# Dynamic Cast Faild - AnyObject to NSArray

Tags: iphone, swift

I am trying to read textFields values which is coming trough alert controller but I am getting run time error on casting with Anyobject to NSArray

```
alertUserStatus.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Sign Up", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: {                
            alertAction in                
 //let textField:NSArray=alertUserStatus.textFields as AnyObject! as NSArray

 let textField=alertUserStatus.textFields! as AnyObject! as NSArray

            let username:String=textField.objectAtIndex(0) as String
            let password:String=textField.objectAtIndex(1) as String


            var signUpUser=PFUser()
            signUpUser.username=username
            signUpUser.password=password

            signUpUser.signUpInBackgroundWithBlock{

                (success:Bool!,error:NSError!)->Void in

                if success == true {
                    println("sign up successfully")
                }
                else{
                    println("fail to sign up")
                }
            }


        }))
```

Comment: i tried two ways to cast anyobjec with nsarray but its giving me run time error

Answer (score 0):

It always helps to look at the type you are getting from a function before trying to massage it into another type.  In this case `alertUserStatus.textFields` returns `[AnyObject]?` – that is, an optional array of `AnyObject`.  So there’s really no need to convert it to an `AnyObject` and then to an `NSArray` just so you can get the first two entries from it.  Instead you want to unwrap it and convert it to an array of `String`.

It’s also best to avoid using `!`, even if you’re confident the optional can’t possibly be `nil`, because one of these days there’ll be an edge case that you miss that doesn’t hold and your code will crash with an inexplicable force-unwrap error message.

```
// nb you can skip the handler: argument name with trailing-closure syntax
alertUserStatus.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Sign Up", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default) {
    alertAction in

    if let textFields = alertUserStatus.textFields as? [String] where textFields.count > 1 {

        let username = textFields[0]
        let password = textFields[1]

        // rest of your code...
    }
    else {
        // assert with intelligible message or log error or similar
    }
})
```